# AngularJs - Assign Value to scope variable inline

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

It's a fairly simple problem, I am using AngularJS v1.7.2 with C# MVC.

I got my standard setup with Layout pages and Views. 
I load my AngularJs controllers/services from external script files so there's nothing on the Views.

My problem is that I want to assign a value from ViewBag to a controller variable, but I obviously can't reference ViewBag in a script as it needs to be done on the cshtml page.

I have tried doing it inside ng-init like so

```
<div ng-init="City = @ViewBag.City"></div>
```

Or

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">{{CityId = '1'}}</div>
```

I tried variations with `{{City = @ViewBag.City}}`, `'@ViewBag.City'` and couple of others I saw on StackOverflow to no avail.

I load my scripts on the view using:

```
@section Page_Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/angular/ngListing")
}
```

That obviously is loaded in Layout. My controller works fine so that's not the issue.

My controller is making an ajax call upon initialization, at that point I need the `$scope.City` to be populated with the right value, however it's always set at 0.

Here's what my controller + service (combined for sake of SO) looks like:

```
_mainApp.controller("ListingCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.City = 0;
    $scope.Attractions = [];
    $scope.Offset = 0;
    $scope.Pages = new Array(10);

    var MakeRequest = function (offset) {
        $http.post("/City/GetStuff?City=" + $scope.City + "&Offset=" + offset).then(function (resp) {
            $scope.Attractions = resp.data;
        });
    }

    MakeRequest($scope.Offset);

    $scope.PageUp = function () {
        $scope.Offset++;
        MakeRequest($scope.Offset);
    }

    $scope.PageDown = function () {
        $scope.Offset--;
        MakeRequest($scope.Offset);
    }

    $scope.GoTo = function (offset) {
        $scope.Offset = offset;
        MakeRequest(offset);
    }

});
```

Any solution that is not hacky-ish would be appreciated. It can include directives or a way to assign a value to $scope.City but inline, or at least get my `ViewBag.City` value passed to the controller somehow.

Comment: I don't know how much of hack-ish this could sound to you, but you could try using a hidden value `<input type"hidden" ng-model="city" value="@ViewBag.City" />` and then use `$scope.city` in the angularjs controller.

Comment: I tried this already, what I observed is that the value is displayed for few ms then it's set to 0 as per controller.

Comment: Oh, well, then try removing this line from controller `$scope.City = 0;` and in the input call the controller initialization logic, which is in this case `MakeRequest` like this: `<input type"hidden" ng-model="city" value="@ViewBag.City" ng-init="MakeRequest(Offset)" />`. Also make sure to load the scripts once the MVC values such as `@ViewBag.City` are ready to populate the input value. With this we do not assign the value of `$scope.City` in the controller but in the view.

Comment: @georgeawg Yes, I thought it would be that simple hence why I didn't post it on SO from the beginning and tried to fiddle with it. However upon making the $http request $scope.City is undefined.

Comment: Possibly because the MVC renderer hasn't fully rendered (and processed)  all required values and the scripts start loading.

Comment: @lealceldeiro As I said, I can observe the value changing from 1 to 0. However guys, thanks a lot. I used similar logic to what you've said however; I used ng-init to pass my ViewBag value to my "constructor" method (Not really a constructor) and then assign it to a scope variable and works fine. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it since it put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function in the `ng-init` directive:

```
<div ng-init="initCity(@ViewBag.City)"></div>
```

Define the function in the controller:

```
$scope.initCity = function(city) {
    $scope.city = city;
    MakeRequest($scope.offset, $scope.city);
};

function MakeRequest(offset,city) {
    var url = "/City/GetStuff";
    var params = {city:city, offset:offset};
    var config = {params: params};
    $http.get(url,config).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.Attractions = resp.data;
    });
}
```

This way the controller will wait for the `ng-init` directive.

Comment: Exactly what I've got, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Something so simple.. completely overthought that!